# Fade out instantly and fade in with CSS3 transitions

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have problem.

I want to instantly fade out my square (after clicking a button)  then afterwards, fade it in slowly with a delayed time.

This is my example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qFYL7/6/

I changed the class but i'm afraid it's not the proper approach:

```
 my_square.className  = 'dim_fast';
 my_square.className = 'square';
```

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qFYL7/9/ > take a look

Comment: I wanted fade in slowly (not fade out).

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your function you're changing the class to `dim_fast` and then immediately back to `square`, which has no transitions :)

So, remove:

```
my_square.className = 'square';
```

Or at least append the 2nd class:

```
my_square.className = 'square dim_fast';
```

---

To fade out the square, and then fade in after an amount of time, you can use `setTimeout`.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sGDDL/)

Comment: But I want to. Fade out - immediately. Than fade in with transition

Comment: No, there are probably others too. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: And how are you toggling by hand?

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood. Thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 2):

### HOW ABOUT A PURE CSS3 SOLUTION?

First you need to make sure that the button is positioned before the square.

```
<button id="bt1"> </button>
<div id="my_square" class="square"> </div>
```

This is because CSS doesn't have a "previous sibling" selector.

Now you must use the `:active` pseudo-element on the button, to directly hide the square.

```
#bt1:active + .square
{

    -webkit-transition:opacity 0s;
       -moz-transition:opacity 0s;
         -o-transition:opacity 0s;    
            transition:opacity 0s;
    opacity:0;
}
```

When you click the button, the square will instantly be hidden.

Now add the transition on the square.

```
.square
{

    -webkit-transition:opacity 2s;
       -moz-transition:opacity 2s;
         -o-transition:opacity 2s;
            transition:opacity 2s;
    opacity:1;
}
```

The Square will Fade In in 2 seconds.

**[CHECK IT OUT](http://jsfiddle.net/pbvED/4/)**

Comment: Why you didn't add webkit and opera prefixes  (and one without)?
Of course It works but anyway I need to trigger it from JS. But Thanks!

Comment: And It can't be "any chosen element" but the following one (because of + operator)  right ?

Comment: @bluesm yes directly the following one.

Comment: You should **always** put the unprefixed one last. Otherwise, the prefixed one is going to get used even if the unprefixed one is supported (as it is the case today with current versions of Firefox and Opera).

Answer (score 0):

I would use animation for this instead of transitions

Altered CSS (*from your jsfiddle*)

```
.square
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;    
    background-color:blue;
    opacity:1;
}
.fade{
    animation: dim_fast_shine_slow 1s;
}
@keyframes dim_fast_shine_slow{
    99%{opacity:0;}
    100%{opacity:1}
}
```

Altered script

```
var my_square = document.getElementById('my_square');

function dim_fast_shine_slow()
{
    // remove class
    my_square.className = my_square.className.replace(' fade','');
    setTimeout(function(){
        // add class after 50 millisecons to allow the DOM to register the removal of the class
        my_square.className  += ' fade';
    },50);

  }

 document.getElementById('bt1').onclick = dim_fast_shine_slow;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qFYL7/7/

Comment: I Thought about opposite direction (instantly fade out, slow fade in)

And I couldn't make it work for chrome even when I do @-webkit-keyframes

Comment: @bluesm for webkit you need to use `-webkit-animation` to apply it see http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qFYL7/12/ (*to invert the direction you also need to set `opacity:0` for **0%** and `opacity:1` for 100%*)

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you very much. There is no way to do this effect without "setTimeout" ?  (because the styles of class aren't apply by browsers immediately but after some time ?)

Comment: There is not event for "register the removal of the class" ?

Comment: @bluesm, both your solutions are just fine.. animations just allow for more than two states..

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
function dim_fast_shine_slow() {
    my_square.classList.toggle("dim_fast");
}
```

In your version you had:

```
function dim_fast_shine_slow() {
    my_square.className  = 'dim_fast'; //changes class to dim_fast
    my_square.className = 'square'; // changes it back to square
}
```

In each click the element's class name will just end up being "square".

Comment: Sorry. But This require "two clicks" instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2018 and [this solution](https://codepen.io/yaplusplus/pen/EQyrbV) works in edge, chrome, opera and firefox. Does'nt work in my IE11 though caniuse says IE11 has full keyframes support.

```js
const fade = document.querySelector('.fade');
const cont = document.querySelector('.container');

document.body.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if (ev.target.classList.contains('fade')) {
    cont.classList.add('fade-out-in');
  }
});

cont.addEventListener('animationend', ev => {
  cont.classList.remove('fade-out-in');
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeOutIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.fade-out-in {
  animation: fadeOutIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<button class="fade">Fade 1</button>
<button class="fade">Fade 2</button>
<button class="fade">Fade 3</button>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

There should be a way of doing it without jQuery (which I am not aware of).. but in case u decide use jQuery :

```
$(my_square).hide("fast").show("slow");
```

Comment: the OP is not using jQuery.